# Cauchy sequences depending on the metric

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'm starting to study Cauchy sequences, could someone give an example of a sequence in R that is Cauchy with some metric but it is not with the Euclidean metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a classic: take $x_n=n$ and the metric $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$.